# Split a word in an Excel cell into separate columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to split a cell containing a word (no spaces or delimiters) into individual columns. For example in A1 I have a word 'ABCD' and I would like to split this as follows B1: 'A', C1: 'B', D1: 'C' and E1: 'D'. I tried using 'Text to Columns' to no success. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using vba for this?

Comment: From what I searched it seems that you have to have a delimiter, which in my case I do not.

Comment: do you want to split every char into one cell?

Comment: Text to columns with a fixed width of `1` for each column works fine for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use MID:

```
=MID($A1,COLUMN(A:A),1)
```

put that in the first cell and drag over.

---

If one has access to the new dynamic array formula `SEQUENCE` it can be done with:

```
=MID(A1,SEQUENCE(1,LEN(A1)),1)
```

Without the need to copy the formula over.  Excel will spill the results to the right.

Comment: Thats not very dynamic. For every new word he has to drag that over over and over again.

Comment: When I use this and drag over it picks up the second value of the adjacent cell not the second character of the same cell

Comment: OK it works! I simply added $ to your formula (=MID($A1,COLUMN(A:A),1). Thank you

Comment: @elstiv Still, if you only dragged it 6 times, then youd have to drag again should you type a word containing 7 characters

Comment: @elstiv Yup, was in a meeting and did it on my phone.  Good Catch.

Comment: @EmilHov There is nothing wrong with copying the formula over 20 or 30 columns they will be blank past the length of the word.

Answer (score 0):

Scott Cramers answer was mostly correct from what I can see, just needed absolute positioning:

=MID($A1,COLUMN(A:A),1)

It's pretty inefficient and only works on 1 character at a time though.Can't think of anything better at the mo.

Answer (score 0):

Try using VBA. Put this code in the code of your sheet and it will automatically update your cell values if you change the word.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then 'Change $A$1 to the address of your cell.
        Dim str As String
        Dim index As Integer

        str = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tabelle1").Range("A1").Value

        For i = 1 To Len(str)
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(1, i + 1) = Mid(str, i, 1)
        Next i

    End If
End Sub
```